# NestJs Micro service event based architecture

Tags: microservices, nestjs

My problem is the following.
Considering a micro service architecture with nestJs, some action are triggered by event.

Assume I have "user service" that throw "user.created" event when ne user is registered on DB, some others services can listen this event.
If a service scale, mean there are more than & instance a a service running in same time, the message is consumed many time by the same "kind of service".

How can I resolve this problem ?

Her you'll find a complete example project with above use case and running code : https://github.com/quentin-bardenet/nest-u-service-scalability-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's ok, I replace Redis transporter by NATS.
NATS support queue then I can create kind of groups.

I updated the previous repository with the working code, maybe it could help someone.